# Batch file not moving files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

for some reason if I run the batch file from different location other the `sDir` it will not move the files

```
@ECHO OFF &CLS
::// The Input Folder
SET $sDir="C:\Temp"

:: The Output Folders
SET $Out305="C:\Documents\completed"

::// Set Files extensions
SET "$Format=*.pdf,*.doc,*.jpg"

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

:Loop
cls&echo Waiting for file !!!
for /f %%a in ('dir /b/a-d %$sDir%\%$Format% 2^>nul') do (
 SET "$Fichier=%%a"
 ECHO Treating _^> %%a
 if "!$Fichier:~0,3!"=="305" move "%%~nxa" %$Out305%
)

::// Waiting ~5 seconds
ping localhost -n 6 >nul

::// Return to the loop
goto:Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why your code fails? You are using a `for /f` command to process the output of a `dir /b` command. This output does not include folder information unless `/s` switch is used to do a recursive search. So, as the **string** (not a reference to a file found by a `for`) being processed does not include a folder, none of the following commands

```
MOVE "%%~nxa" .... ( only name and extension, no path )
MOVE "%%a" ....    ( only name and extension, the string does not include path )
MOVE "%%~fa" ....  ( path generated using the active directory, not file folder )
```

will found the file as it is not located in the current folder (the first two) or has a wrong path (the third one).

You will need something like

```
MOVE "%$sDir%\%%a" ....
```

But as your variables also include quotes, you will have to change the `set` commands to

```
SET "$sDir=c:\temp"
```

That is, the quotes should not be included in the value if later we need to concatenate the value.

Anyway, as the only thing that the code is doing to move the files starting with `305` to a target folder and repeat the process, this can be simplified as

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "inputFolder=c:\temp"
    set "output305=c:\documents\completed"
    set "extensions=.pdf .doc .jpg"

    for /l %%a in (0) do (
        for %%b in (%extensions%) do 2>nul move /y "%inputFolder%\305*%%~b" "%output305%"
        >nul ping localhost -n 6 
    )
```

An infinite loop (`for /l %%a in (0)`) that will iterate over the indicated list of extensions and move any file in the input folder, starting with `305` and with a matching extension into the target folder.

Comment: @Omar, what is what you tested? My code does not show any `0 file(s) moved` message.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but to me your code is a mess. I'll try to clean it up and to solve the problem.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

:: The Input Folder
SET sDir="C:\Temp"

:: The Output Folders
SET Out305="C:\Documents\completed"

:: Set Files extensions
SET "Format=*.pdf,*.doc,*.jpg"

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

:Loop
CLS
ECHO Waiting for file!!!
FOR /F %%a IN ('DIR /b/a-d %sDir%\%Format% 2^>nul') DO (
    SET "Fichier=%%a"
    ECHO Treating _^> %%a
    IF "!Fichier:~0,3!"=="305" MOVE "%%a" %Out305%
)

:: Waiting ~5 seconds
PING localhost -n 6 >nul

:: Return to the loop
GOTO Loop
```

I guess the problem is this line:

```
IF "!Fichier:~0,3!"=="305" move "%%~nxa" %Out305%
```

Your source is `%%~nxa`, means the name and the extention of `%%a`. But this way you just ignore the path to the file and the script will only look for it in it's own directory. The fix schould be just to replace `%%~nxa` with `%%a` or `%%~dpnxa`. Please tell me if it helps.

PS: I'd like to offer you some tips about clean code in batch. Just skip the rest of the post if you're not interested.

Don't use special characters like $ in variable names. This is uncommon in batch coding and might cause trouble in very unexpected situations.

Some people like to type commands in capital letters (PING, ECHO, CLS), others don't (dir, for, if). To keep your code clean you should try to skick to one convention. Line like theese make your code ugly to read:

> ECHO Treating _^> %%a
>
> if "!$Fichier:~0,3!"==...

Comment: Thanks for the help and the advice   I'm still in the learning curve

Comment: hay buddy I am getting `Treating_> 305678910.pdf`   `system cannot find the file specified` its not moving any files

Comment: okay I have tried  replacing `%%~nxa` with `%%a` and `%%~dpnxa` and did not work, Thanks I will have to go with @MC ND code